# Counting down from N to 1

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to create a list and print it out, counting down from N to 1. This is my attempt:

```
%% Create a list counting down from N to 1 %%
-module(list).
-export([create_list/1]).

create_list(N) when length(N)<hd(N) ->
 lists:append([N],lists:last([N])-1),
 create_list(lists:last([N])-1); 
create_list(N) ->
 N.
```

This works when N is 1, but otherwise I get this error:

```
172> list:create_list([2]).
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in function  list:create_list/1 (list.erl, line 6)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is `lists:last([N])-1`. Since N is an array as your input, `lists:last([N])` will return N itself.  Not a number you expect. And if you see the warning when compiling your code, there is another bug: `lists:append` will not append the element into N itself, but in the return value. In functional programming, the value of a variable cannot be changed.

Here's my implementation:

```
create_list(N) ->
    create_list_iter(N, []).

create_list_iter(N, Acc) ->
    case N > 0 of
        true -> NewAcc = lists:append(Acc, [N]),
                create_list_iter(N-1, NewAcc);
        false -> Acc
    end.
```

Comment: Using `append` (or `++`) is something you should avoid when possible as it entails making a new copy of the list to add an element to the end of the list.

Answer (score 4):

You should generally avoid using `append` or `++`, which is the same thing, when building lists. They both add elements to the **end** of a list which entails making a copy of the list every time. Sometimes it is practical but it is always faster to work at the front of the list.

It is a bit unclear in which order you wanted the list so here are two alternatives:

```
create_up(N) when N>=1 -> create_up(1, N).     %Create the list 

create_up(N, N) -> [N];
create_up(I, N) ->
    [I|create_up(I+1, N)].

create_down(N) when N>1 ->                     %Add guard test for safety
    [N|create_down(N-1)];
create_down(1) -> [1].
```

Neither of these are tail-recursive. While tail-recursion is nice it doesn't always give as much as you would think, especially when you need to call a `reverse` to get the list in the right order. See [Erlang myths](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#tail_recursive) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand your question, here is what you'll need

```
create_list(N) when N > 0 ->
        create_list(N, []).

create_list(1, Acc) ->
        lists:reverse([1 | Acc]);
create_list(N, Acc) ->
        create_list(N - 1, [N | Acc]).
```

If you work with lists, I'd suggest you to **use tail recursion** and **lists construction syntax**.

Also, to simplify your code - try to **use pattern matching** in function  declarations, instead of case expressions

**P.S.**
The other, perhaps, most simple solution is:

```
create_list(N) when N > 0 ->
        lists:reverse(lists:seq(1,N)).
```

Comment: Or even easier `lists:seq(10,1,-1).` but that's cheating.

Comment: @rvirding That's exactly what I was about to suggest :)